# How to bind a property from my usercontrol content control to a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have a UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MySample.customtextbox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
       <TextBox x:Name="Ytextbox"  Background="Yellow"/> 
</Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

I want use my control in mvvm pattern ...i want that i can bind a property in my viewmodel to Ytextbox Text Property

```
<CT:customtextbox  ?(Ytextbox)Text ="{binding  mypropertyinviewmodel}"/>
```

...how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a property on the UserControl and bind that internally to the TextBox's text.

i.e.

```
<UserControl Name="control" ...>
    <!-- ... -->
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=control}"
                 Background="Yellow"/>
```

```
public class customtextbox : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        TextBox.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(customtextbox));
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<CT:customtextbox Text="{Binding  mypropertyinviewmodel}"/>
```

*(Do not set the DataContext in the UserControl to itself unless you want all external bindings which expect the DataContext to be inherited to fail, use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` for internal bindings)*

Comment: I got a little confused because the `TextBox` property name and the custom control propery was the same and I intended a different property name, but after I realized what to change it worked :) +1 Thanks